# Python - Find and get the position of element in array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a json file like below

```
{

    "sample": 100,
    "columns": [{
            "name": "col1",
            "value": 11
        },
        {
            "name": "col2",
            "value": 210
        }, 
                ..... 
        {
            "name": "col10",
            "value": 20
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to find the position of `name: col10` in the columns array.

Comment: Do you want its position only?

Comment: Yes, only the position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like the below

```
data = {

    "sample": 100,
    "columns": [{
        "name": "col1",
        "value": 11
    },
        {
            "name": "col2",
            "value": 210
        },
        {
            "name": "col10",
            "value": 20
        }
    ]
}

col_name = 'col2'
for idx, entry in enumerate(data['columns']):
    if entry['name'] == col_name:
        print(f'index of {col_name} is {idx}')
        # assuming it can be found once - break
        break
```

output

```
index of col2 is 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using `dropwhile` from `itertools`. This loops through an iterable until the function passed to it returns false. It then returns a generator containing every item from that point onwards.

```
from itertools import dropwhile

data = {
    "sample": 100,
    "columns": [
        {"name": "col1", "value": 11},
        {"name": "col2", "value": 210},
        {"name": "col10", "value": 20},
    ],
}

def col10_not_found(index_dict_tuple):
    return index_dict_tuple[1]["name"] != "col10"

print(next(dropwhile(col10_not_found, enumerate(data["columns"])))[0])
# output: 2
```

Note that this will break if `col10` is not found, this is merely an illustration of how to get to the desired result. The missing `col10` could be handled by handling `StopIteration`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
import json


with open('data.json') as f:
    columns = json.load(f)['columns']

try:
    position = next(
      idx for idx, col in enumerate(columns)
      if col['name'] == 'col10'
    )
except StopIteration:
    print('No such element')
else:
    print('Position:', position)
```